# Start data-scroll-speed only from certain moment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using `data-scroll-speed=`to control the scroll speed of a certain div.
The data-scroll-speed is entered as a tag:

```
<div id="myDiv1" data-scroll-speed="3">this is a test</div>.
```

What I want is that the div does not adopt the scroll speed controlled by data-scroll-speed untill another div's (id= "myDiv2") bottom egde is above the bottom edge of the browser window. Otherwise myDiv1 must scroll at normal speed. How can this be achieved?

Comment: you can start by trying out something with the scroll event on window and check some heights here and there

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var $myDiv1 = $('#myDiv1');
  var $myDiv2 = $('#myDiv2');

  var bottom = $myDiv2.position().top + $myDiv2.outerHeight(true);
  
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= bottom) {
      console.log('Scroll Speed Set!');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

div {
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#myDiv2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv1" data-scroll-speed="3">this is a test</div>
<div id="myDiv2">myDiv2</div>
```